# MS Access IIF Field Exists

Tags: ms-access-2010

I am creating a report from a query where a field ABC is displayed as CAT if yes and as MOUSE if no. But unfortunately, when there are instances where the table inside the query does not contain field ABC, the report generates a error pop-up. Is there any way to by-pass this and run the report with other fields excluding the missing field?

I heard that `IIF` Exist function could help, but I am really blank here. I wrote the access query like below:

```
Iif (fieldExists(iif([ABC]=5, 'CAT', 'MOUSE'),iif([ABC]=5, 'CAT', 'MOUSE'), ''))  AS TOMnJERRY
```

Comment: Are you saying that your table structure can change so that it may or may not contain a field (column) named 'ABC'? If so, you should be receiving a prompt for parameter 'ABC' (if a field is undefined, it assumes it is user supplied).  Or do you mean there is no value of YES or NO?

Comment: You are correct. I get a parameter ABC pop-up. I want to bypass this error and display the report. Can you help me plz?

Answer (score 1):

This function is maybe the shortest one to test if a field exists in Access:

```
Function FieldExists(ByVal Table As String, ByVal Field As String) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    FieldExists = (DCount(Field, Table) >= 0)
End Function
```

How it works:
If the field exists, the expression `(DCount(Field, Table) >= 0)` is obviously always `true`, because `DCount` never returns a negative value. If the field doesn't exist, an error will occur and the program will jump to the next line without setting the return variable `FieldExist`, so this one will keep at default and this is `false`.

So the solution for your problem should look like this:

```
Iif (FieldExists('YourTable','ABC'), iif([ABC]=5, 'CAT', 'MOUSE'), '')
```